# Items are showing blank in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TableData` class:

```cs
public class TableData
{
    public string ID, WrestlerID;
    public string Name;
}
```

And some data that I then put on a list:

```cs
List<TableData> _tableData = new List<TableData>();
TableData tableData = new TableData
{
    ID = "0",
    WrestlerID = "000",
    Name = "test1"
};
_tableData.Add(tableData);
TableData tableData2 = new TableData
{
    ID = "1",
    WrestlerID = "111",
    Name = "test2"
};
_tableData.Add(tableData2);
```

I then iterate through my `_tableData` list and add each item on my DataGrid:

```cs
foreach (TableData data1 in _tableData)
{
    DGTable.Items.Add(data1);
}
```

BTW Here's my DataGrid:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="DGTable" Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wrestler ID" Binding="{Binding WrestlerID}" Width="200"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I run the app, the DataGrid displays 2 rows but all fields are empty. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Your `TableData` class needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface and your fields should be observable properties.

Comment: Thank you @ewerspej for that! Can you please show me how to do that through an answer? I'm pretty new on `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `observable properties` part.

Comment: Why are you populating the DataGrid in a loop? You could also bind to an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) using the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` property instead of "manually" placing items from a List into the DataGrid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#binding-to-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TableData` class needs to have properties instead of fields to be able use bindings.

It should also implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface to use observable properties, so that changes to those properties get reflected in the UI.

Change your class as follows:

```cs
public class TableData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
  
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  

    private string id;
    public string ID
    {
        get => id;
        set
        {
            if(id == value) return;
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // repeat for WrestlerID and Name
    //...
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.ComponentModel;` at the top.

Comment: This gave me an error `id was null`

Comment: in the `if (id.Equals(value)) return;` part

Comment: Right, because `id` isn't initialized, unassigned strings are `null`. For your purposes `id == value` should be sufficient, but you can also initialize it to `string.Empty`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is necessary only when *property changes* are expected (as the name suggests). Bindings will work with any public properties, observable or not.

Comment: Yes, but only once. Changes won't get reflected. I updated the answer for clarification.